# mostrar datos de tabla relacionada con LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Estimados amigos buenas noches.

tengo un metodo para llenar clientes por nombre en un datagridview este es mi codigo:

```
    public List<CLIENTES> GetClientesByNombre(string nombre)
    {
        using (RSAEntities db = new RSAEntities())
        {
            //return db.CLIENTES.ToList();

            var Query = (from c in db.CLIENTES
                         where c.CLI_NOMBRE.StartsWith(nombre)
                         orderby c.CLI_NOMBRE
                         select c).ToList();

            return Query;

        }
    }
```

en mi formulario estoy llenando el datagridview en forma manual.

```
    private void btnListar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtNombre.Text.ToString().Trim().Length==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un Nombre");
            txtNombre.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            NCliente nCliente = new NCliente();
            List<CLIENTES> lista = new List<CLIENTES>();
            lista = nCliente.GetClientesByNombre(txtNombre.Text.ToString().Trim());
            dgvClientes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgvClientes.DataSource = lista;
        }

    }
```

en modo de diseno manejo las columnas ejm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como muestro el campo GRU_NOMBRE de la entidad GRUPO que esta relacionada a la entidad CLIENTE??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos por su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: Has probado con `GRUPO.GRU_NOMBRE`?  De todas maneras lo mejor es que depures la aplicación y veas que datos tienes en `lista` despues de cargar los datos.

Comment: Lo probe con GRUPO.GRU_NOMBRE no funciona.

Comment: Pone en la columna **Grupo**  en la propiedad del **DataPropertyName** el mismo nombre que aparece en el **MODELO DE DATOS** (la tabla del entityFramework).

Answer (score 1):

Debes asegurarte de incluir también la información de la entidad GRUPO: Usando el método de extensión .Include() que se encuentra en el espacio de nombre System.Data.Entity en el caso de EntityFramework 6.0

```
public List<CLIENTES> GetClientesByNombre(string nombre)
{
    using (RSAEntities db = new RSAEntities())
    {
        //return db.CLIENTES.ToList();

        var Query = (from c in db.CLIENTES.Include(c => c.GRUPO)
                     where c.CLI_NOMBRE.StartsWith(nombre)
                     orderby c.CLI_NOMBRE
                     select c).ToList();

        return Query;

    }
}
```

Finalmente como dice @Pikoh prueba con GRUPO.GRU_NOMBRE en el DataGridView